# Making Map Markers Clickable Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on creating an app which contains various markers on a map. These markers should be clickable, and when clicked a new activity should be started. I can't for the life of me figure out why nothing happens when they're clicked. I've done hours of research and tried tens of different solutions but can't seem to get anything to happen when the markers are clicked. Please help!

```
public class GlobalAlerts extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {


    private ImageView goBack, backgroundColor;
    private TextView disasterType, selectorText;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    ArrayList<LatLng> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<AlertData> allAlerts = new ArrayList<>();
    private GoogleMap gMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        allAlerts = (ArrayList<AlertData>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("NAME");

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        for (int i=0;i<allAlerts.size();i++){
            latlngs.add(new LatLng(allAlerts.get(i).getLat(),allAlerts.get(i).getLong()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gMap=googleMap;


        for(int i=0;i<latlngs.size();i++){
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlngs.get(i)).title(String.valueOf(allAlerts.get(i).getID())));
                gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlngs.get(i)));
        }

        this.gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        System.out.println("I'm finally working");
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT - I've now copied the exact code supplied by google at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker and it is still not working, making me think that it might be an issue with something else??

Comment: Is it opening info window? in built info window?

Comment: No info window, absolutely nothing happens when the markers are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - All the code is correct, but android studio and its supporting services were not up to date. This caused an issue which did not allow for the onclicklistener to work. Note to self - make sure everything is always up to date!